# For loop to count multi record

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is my code

```
public function count_er($str_arr){
    for($i=0;$i<=count($str_arr);$i++){
            $counter=("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `number` where `group_id`='$str_arr[$i]'");
            $q = mysqli_query($this->con,$counter);
            $row .= $q->fetch_row();
        }   
        return $row[0];
        mysqli_close($this>con);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using a single query, and using a prepared statement. Then loop over all the results and store them in an array, which you return.

```php
public function count_er(array $str_arr) {
    $result = [];
    $query = "SELECT group_id, COUNT(*)
              FROM `number` 
              WHERE `group_id` IN (".trim(str_repeat("?,", count($str_arr)), ',').")
              GROUP BY `group_id`";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare($query);

    // "i" for integers, "s" for strings
    $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("i", count($str_arr)), ...$str_arr);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_param($group_id, $count);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $result[$group_id] = $count;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: thank you but i dont know how many groups id in array and i wont count all numbers from the groups

Comment: This will return the result of all the IDs in the array, since we use a `WHERE group_id IN (..)` query. Did you try it?